# How do I Invert search using grep for multiple strings of text

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I am trying filter out couple of blocks of text that keep repeating over and over in my log file. For eg;

```
grep -v ("string one that I don't want" \| "string two that I don't want") file.log
```

I tried several variations of this and tried tweaking the white spaces . Sometimes it will filter out the first string sometimes neither. What will be the correct format to filter out more than one block of text using grep ?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use `-e` option multiple times in `grep` to skip multiple search items:

```
grep -v -e "string one that I don't want" -e "string two that I don't want" file.log
```

OR else use `regex` using `grep -E` for extended regex support:

```
grep -vE 'string one|string two' file.log
```

Comment: Thank you. Both method works. I had tried using that egrep method. But I think I put space in between the pipe character. So it didn't work at the time. Now it works.

Comment: Note to googlers like me: `-v` [is synonymous to](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) `--invert-match` (I would have guessed “verbose” and stumbled :)